# specify number of digits returned

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a quantity that I want displayed as a whole number so I am using the below statement.

```
concat(CAST(oe_pick_ticket_detail.unit_quantity AS DECIMAL(10,0))
```

Right now it is returning `400`

I'd like it to be an 8 digit number like this `00000400`

How should I modify this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The method depends on the database.  Zero-padding integers tends to be database-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SQL Server 2012+

```
Select Format(oe_pick_ticket_detail.unit_quantity,'00000000')           -- Returns 00000400
```

Another non-format option

```
Select right(concat('00000000',oe_pick_ticket_detail.unit_quantity),8)  -- Returns 00000400
```

Comment: Im not sure where to drop this when using concat and cast.  This is sql 2012.  I also only want this applied to the field that i am casting. in this case, unit_quantity

Comment: @eggwhites is unit_quantity  an int?  If so, just replace the 400 with unit_quantity

Comment: In this case, your answer is perfectly OK (+1 from my side) as it is 2012+, but: The padding with `RIGHT()` and leading zeros is dangerous, if the number exceeds the given width. This will cut the number and return unpredictable values without complaints. Better is `SELECT REPLACE(STR(400,8),' ','0')`. This would return `********`, if the number is wider than 8 digits. So - at least - you'd get an error...

Comment: @Shnugo The Format() option will work with wider than 8 digits.  You are correct regarding the padding, I would rather see  ******** indicating an error rather than trusting a false positive